# CMake doesn't work with spaces when called from Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

I build my Android APKs from the command line on Windows using Gradle. It all works fine except when there is a space in the path name. In that case, Gradle doesn't seem to pass the path correctly to CMake, as can be seen in the console output.

In my `build.gradle` CMake is called like this:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

Now when I compile my project from `C:\test\apktest` all is fine. When I compile it from `C:\test\apk test` (note the space character!) it doesn't work any longer. The console output is this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildArm7Debug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\test\apk test\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\arm7Debug\armeabi-v7a --target myproject}
  Unknown argument test\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\arm7Debug\armeabi-v7a
  Usage: cmake --build <dir> [options] [-- [native-options]]
  Options:
    <dir>          = Project binary directory to be built.
    --target <tgt> = Build <tgt> instead of default targets.
                     May only be specified once.
    --config <cfg> = For multi-configuration tools, choose <cfg>.
    --clean-first  = Build target 'clean' first, then build.
                     (To clean only, use --target 'clean'.)
    --use-stderr   = Ignored.  Behavior is default in CMake >= 3.0.
    --             = Pass remaining options to the native tool.
```

As you can see, CMake is incorrectly started from Gradle because it is started like this: `cmake --build C:\test\apk test\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\arm7Debug\armeabi-v7a --target myproject` but there should be double quotes around the `--build` argument so that it is parsed as a single argument and not as two separate arguments.

I think this is a bug but where should it be reported? Android NDK? Gradle? CMake?

Also, is there any workaround except not using paths with spaces?

Comment: Not every CMake project correctly process spaces in the source/binary directory. So it is better to not use such directories at all when work with CMake.

Comment: This is supposed to be fixed in preview version here: [https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/)